# mean stack authentication - best practice

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

i'm trying to figure out a best practice for building an authentication system, the simplest one (based on user_name and password).

i searched for best practices and found a few projects, although most of them are pretty old and many things are depreciated.

i would like to have some advises for best practices to have the simplest login\signup system using angular-express-mongodb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also look these articles:

- https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/
- https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/27/ten-things-you-should-know-about-tokens-and-cookies/
- http://madhatted.com/2014/6/17/authentication-for-single-page-apps
- https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local
- http://www.frederiknakstad.com/2013/01/21/authentication-in-single-page-applications-with-angular-js/

and these questions on stackoverflow:

- [RESTful Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319530/restful-authentication)
- [SPA best practices for authentication and session management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963273/spa-best-practices-for-authentication-and-session-management)

Answer (score 4):

Use the passport module https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport, it has many modules you can use including one that stores login information in MongoDB https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/tree/master/examples

Comment: i saw that github repo.. although it's not pure mean stack as they don't use angular for client side

Comment: It is independent of the client - you implement the client in whatever framework you want

Answer (score 2):

Another option that seems quite cool is [Satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer), a terrible name, but seems to meet the requirement.