# Persisting 'loggedIn' state after refresh in React

Tags: javascript, flask, reactjs, flask-login

React beginner here and to SPAs in general. I'm trying to make my login state persistent across my app but I struggle with when the user refreshes the page. Currently I have a method in my login form that calls the server to login and I guess receives a cookie (I'm using Flask with the Flask-Login extension). So I thought a simple thing which I've seen in a couple examples is to store the `loggedIn` state in my parent `<App>` component like this:

```
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            loggedIn: false
        }
    }

    logIn = () => {
        this.setState({
            loggedIn: true
        });
    };
```

And then pass the `loggedIn` state and the `logIn()` callback down to the login form. This works fine, but after refresh the `loggedIn` state is `false` again, obviously. Is using the way to do it? If so, how?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: After a bunch of research I realized that Flask-Login is (obviously) a server-side session authentication scheme or whatever. So the cookie it sends is `httpOnly`, so I can't access it using JS as recommended in the first answer. Is there any documentation out there using `httpOnly` session cookies in SPAs?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the loggedIn state in the cookie,. Use the `react-cookie` [npm package.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie)

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        loggedIn: false
    }
}

componentWillMount() {
    var loggedIn = cookie.load('loggedIn');
    if(loggedIn !== undefined) {
        this.setState({loggedIn})
    } 
}
logIn = () => {
    this.setState({
        loggedIn: true
    });
    cookie.save('loggedIn', true);
};
```

Comment: But if the cookie is httpOnly, will this still work? Or do I need a new cookie?

Comment: these cookies will be stored in your brower and hance this will work

Comment: But I thought you can't read httpOnly cookies from the browser?

Comment: With react-cookie you have an option to set the httpOnly cookie, however by default it is false and hence the client and read and modify them. I hope it helps. This is an approach I have also used, so I know that this worjs

Comment: I understand you can create cookies with the flag of httpOnly. But I don't want to create a new cookie. The thing is the server is sending an httpOnly cookie to the browser and saving it because the session management I guess is done on the server. My flask-login knowledge is pretty poor. But I can't touch this cookie anymore. I don't even think you can get it through react. I'm sure there is a common way of doing this I just can't find anything online.

Comment: This is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42824415/single-page-application-with-httponly-cookie-based-authentication-and-session-ma

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround:  I created a `/token` endpoint.  Since the cookie is `httpOnly` and read by Express (using cookie-parser), I can return it as a response json as provided below.

```
// An endpoint to get the httpOnly token
// during React app page refresh.
app
    .get('/token', (req, res) => {
        const token = req.cookies.token;
        res.json({ token: token ? token : null });
    });
```

Now, in React, I can have a `useEffect` (wherever appropriate, I had it in a provider that wraps components) that calls the above endpoint if a page refresh happens.

```
useEffect(() => {
    let isSubscribed = true;
    axios.get('/api/token')
        .then((res) => (isSubscribed && res.data.token
            ? setState(token)
            : null))
        .catch((error) => (isSubscribed
            ? console.error(error)
            : null));
    return () => isSubscribed = false;
}, []);
```

Also refer [**this article**](https://juliangaramendy.dev/blog/use-promise-subscription).