# AJAX with PHP - How to set role based access to PHP URLs

Tags: php, ajax, single-page-application

I'm just getting into SPAs with PHP and AJAX, and from the W3 Example:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?q=" + str, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

You can access the PHP directly at https://www.w3schools.com/php/gethint.php?q=an

I want my website to function similarly in regard to SPA, but I want to ensure that the user is logged in and a 'premium' member to be able to access the URL. Is there something I can do with `SESSION` or something among those lines?

Comment: Wow, this question is all over the place. Of course you can use sessions to store and maintain user information, though I am not sure what your code example has to do with things.

Comment: Sorry, new to PHP and AJAX. I guess I don't know how to ask my question then.

Comment: All you're really doing is RESTful authentication. Here's 2 links to get started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963273/spa-best-practices-for-authentication-and-session-management & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319530/restful-authentication

Comment: @waterloomatt thanks for the links, that's just what I was looking for! Feel free to post as an answer I can select as best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're implementing RESTful authentication which is covered in these 2 topics.

1. [RESTful Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319530/restful-authentication)
2. [SPA best practices for authentication and session management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963273/spa-best-practices-for-authentication-and-session-management)