# Is this a secure authentication flow (with Auth0 and SvelteKit)?

Tags: access-token, auth0, sveltekit

As there is currently no Auth0 SDK for SvelteKit, I am learning (or at least trying to learn) far more about authentication than I originally intended when setting out to incorporate Auth0 into my SvelteKit app (including server side authentication). The documentation is a little confusing (or maybe it is just massive, or maybe I am just not that bright), so I was hoping to describe my auth flow here for critique (in the hope that this will be helpful to others in the future).

I have reviewed [this great post about SPA auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963273/spa-best-practices-for-authentication-and-session-management) as well as [Auth0's educational offerings](https://auth0.com/docs/videos/learn-identity-series/calling-an-api?origin_team=T025590N6#wistia_yw6hmdhnft?time=2126). Still I am not sure I am connecting the dots properly. Here is my flow. All of this occurs over SSL only.

1. I create an Auth0 client on the client side using their client SDK ([@auth0/auth0-spa-js](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spa-js)). That client performs authentication via the Auth0 popup.
2. Once authenticated, everything works as expected on the client side. But if I want to control access to routes on the server side, I need to get information back to the server. So...
3. After authenticating, Auth0 creates an ID token (a signed JWT) which is stored in the browser's local storage. I save it as a session cookie (with `SameSite=strict; HTTPOnly; Secure;` options set) so that it gets passed back to the server with requests for route authorization.

So let me pause right here...I understand that (at least according to some including the Auth0 educational video linked above) the ID token is not supposed to be used for authentication and should never be passed around. That is what an access token is for. However, in this scenario where the exchange is all first party (my client, my server), it is my understanding that it is "ok".

However, it does make me nervous that the Auth0 SDK is not setting the cookie itself. This makes me wonder if I am Doing It Wrong™.

4. On the server I validate the id_token using a public key, and can then save user details, etc. on the backend if I wish, and allow access to appropriate routes (via `hooks.server.js` in the case of my SvelteKit app).
5. When the user logs out, or if the token expires, the cookie is removed.

(As a side note, I have yet to figure out how to refresh the ID token when it expires as the Auth0 client SDK does not seem to ever update the ID token in the browser storage even if it is expired.)

Is that a secure and typical way of going about it?

(For a work in progress working example, see my [svelteauth0 repo](https://github.com/ejkreboot/svelteauth0).)